# Codeigniter Rest api not working in http or http case

Tags: api, codeigniter, http, https

I am working on codeigniter api,after completing API I have uploaded code to server and all apis working but all of the sudden api showing error "unkown method"  I am using "http://example.com/app/ws"  so getting error, If I use "https://example.com/app/ws" api  working I need api it should work if I use http or https because some time ssl certificate expire in that https nworking and if domain in https then http not working I need http or https both should work how to do this using .htacess I am attaching my code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to get the api from another CodeIgniter application?
If yes, you may try this on the 2nd app :

```
$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  

$json   = file_get_contents('http://thelink', false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));

$data   = json_decode($json, true);
```